# GPX to line doesn't work properly in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, gpx

When I add GPX layers ([this](http://cycling.waymarkedtrails.org/nl/routebrowser/112582/gpx) one, for example) through the GPX to feature tool in Arcmap, the layer shows up as points logically.

Then I try to convert these points to a polyline (in this case bicycle routes) using the points to line tool but the lines always show up strangely, like this:
Sorting field with OBJECTID doesn't change it, neither does 'close line' option.

What should I do?

Image for clarity:

[image: example]]

Comment: The problem with that GPX is its lack of attributes. Inside it has a bunch of segments, which is fine. However theres nothing that defines a segment from another segment with an attribute. So the GPX to Features tool just converts the items, as they find them (which isn't in a continuous order). So the points inside arcgis dont follow the order you'd expect, thus the Points to Line tool creates the lines from one segment to the next.  You'll either need to hack the GPX or the points before converting to lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks okay in QGIS 2.10 pisa
 [image]

There is a lack of attributes only track_id seems to be populated

Comment: QGIS must add in a trackID as there isn't any in the GPX file. Curious, each of those segments, are they in order? OID=0 is first, and next record, OID=1 is the segment immediately after?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mapperz! I converted the GPX file in QGIS to a shapefile and imported that in arcmap, looks great now.

Suppose the Arcmap in-program GPX to Shape converter doesn't work flawless still..